# why I can't use radian as R path in VS Code but R works?

Tags: r, visual-studio

I writed R in VS Code, but today the software alerted "The terminal process *"/opt/anaconda3/bin/radian '--no-site-file'" failed to launch (exit code: 1)."* and R is unattached when I run a R script.

Maybe due to I installed some extensions of shell and python, so I uninstalled them. But it still not work.
Finally I changed the R path from "/opt/anaconda3/bin/radian" to "/usr/local/bin/R" in settings by search r.rterm. And now it works.

But I enter "/opt/anaconda3/bin/radian" in command line, I can open the radian.

So why？ I don't like the origin R and prefer radian.

I use:
MacBook Air (M1, 2020)
Visual Studio Code 1.57.1
R  4.1.0
radian 0.5.11

The extensions:
R Extension for Visual Studio Code
shell-format
ShellCheck
shellman

Answer (score 0):

I tried to work with origin R, but I find that R doesn't work either although it can open terminator and output error.

Finally I uninstall VS code, and delete configuration files.

sudo rm -rf $HOME/Library/Application\ Support/Code;
sudo rm -rf $HOME/.vscode

After I install VS code again, it works.

For reference only.